# Entity Framework ignoring data annotation attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have property in my entity:

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
  public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
```

I'm using code first approach. EF successfully creates table for this entities, but for property CreationTime, column parameter Is Computed always set to False.

Comment: Time when row is added to table.

Comment: how about just `public DateTime CreationTime {get; set;} = DateTime.UtcNow;`?